# Microsoft Graph API to Stop Inheriting Permissions in One Drive items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In the OneDrive user interface, it is possible to update a drive item so that the permissions no longer inherit from the parent (Stop Inheriting Permissions). Is it possible to do the same through the Graph API? I can seem to find any call that seems to allow for that. In the documentation for Delete Permissions, it says:
"Only sharing permissions that are not inherited can be deleted. The inheritedFrom property must be null."

We need to be able to programatically set the permissions on drive folders and items and one of the things we have to do is to stop inheritance from parent.

Regards,
LT

Comment: I have been doing more testing and there is some differences in behaviour between what I see in the OneDrive UI and Graph API:

Comment: In the UI, for an item that is in a folder, when I look at the permissions, I can't change them until I hit "Stop Inheriting Permission". But when I look at the permission for that item through graph API, none of the permissions have value for "inheritedFrom" and I am able to delete the permission. Once I delete a permission that is inherited from the parent folder through the API, and the go look in the UI, the permissions for the item are no longer inherited.

Answer (score 2):

i know it's a long time question but here what you can do :

- Get the directory item Id
- Get the permissions id list
  => [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/%7BitemId%7D/permissions)
- Loop over all permissionIds and delete them
- Post a new Invite with all the users/groups you want

The "inherited" is only a list of allow users/groups ... if you delete all of them, your folder become a "only you" folder permission (no inheritance)

I use that in my application, it's not the most simple but it works

Answer (score 1):

I am also struggling with the Graph Api invite-endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I have not found an better solution than @Dadv.

My job is to copy an Sharepoint folder to another folder, including any subfolders.
And then make sure that subfolders get the exactly same permissions as the source subfolders.

Unfortunaly this has to be 2 seperate tasks, when using the Graph Api, using /copy endpoint to copy the subfolders, and for the permissions I use a combination of Delete / Update / Add to syncronize the permissions.

Rather complicated with lots of roundtrips to the API, for such a simple job.

Now I hope to hear from someone who knows of an simpler way of doing the permission part.

Here is some pseudo code to show visualize the syncronization of the permissions.

```
// Now the targetFolders exists --> syncronize permissions

var targetFolderGraphUr = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<id>/items/<item-id>";


// Then apply permissions from template: Update (Patch) or Add (using /invite)
foreach (var sourcePermission in sourceFolderPermissions)
{
    var pcPerm = targetFolderPermissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GrantedTo?.User?.DisplayName == sourcePermission.GrantedTo?.User?.DisplayName);

    // Update
    if (pcPerm != null)
    {
        bool isUpdateNeeded = CheckIfUpdateNeeded(...);

        if (isUpdateNeeded)
        {
            var updateUrl = $"{targetFolderGraphUr}/permissions/{sourcePermission.Id}";
            var updateResult = await myHttpClient.PatchAsync(updateUrl, sourcePermission);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Add 
        var userId = sourcePermission.GrantedTo?.User?.Id;
        var invitePermission = new InvitePermission()
        {
            Recepients = GetRecepientArray( userId ),  // returns a list of recipients, setting objectId = userId
            ObjectId = userId,
            Roles = sourcePermission.Roles,
            RequireSignIn = true,
            SendInvitation = false,
            retainInheritedPermissions = false
        };

        var inviteUrl = $"{targetFolderGraphUr}/invite";

        var inviteResult = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(inviteUrl, invitePermission);

        // response is 200 OK, but no permissions are added.
        // Using Dadv's workarround, deleting all permissions on targetfolder first, then it works.
        // (not shown in this example) 
    }
}


// Finally remove all permissions not existing in the sourcefolder
foreach (var targetPermission in targetFolderPermissions)
{
    if (!sourceFolderPermissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GrantedTo?.User?.DisplayName == targetPermission.GrantedTo?.User?.DisplayName))
    {
        var deleteUrl = $"{targetFolderGraphUr}/permissions/{targetPermission.Id}";
        var deleteResult = await myHttpClient.DeleteAsync(deleteUrl);
    }
}
```